# How tune correct login for entity with spring-secuity, oauth2?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth, jwt

I created an entity with crud operations.
I have used spring-boot, spring-security, oauth2, jwt.
By this article http://sivatechlab.com/secure-rest-api-using-spring-security-oauth2-jwt/

Why do I need to create the table  oauth_client_details?
When I want to login,  first I need to enter login and password from oauth_client_details
[image: first]

And after that enter username and password for my user
[image: second]

How should I tune login for my entity and receive a token after success login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `JdbcTokenStore`, you need to setup `oauth` related table in database. In my template project, I use `JwtTokenStore` for `oauth2` stateless.
So, you don't need any `oauth` related table. [Here](https://github.com/javamutu/mutu-spring-rest) complete `spring-boot-rest` api sample project. You can reference the following thing

1. spring-boot
2. mybatic with mysql
3. ExceptionHandlerAspect
4. LoggingAspect with log4j2
5. ResponseBodyAdvice
6. ResponseEntityExceptionHandler
7. spring-security-5 with oauth2

Run `DB.sql` for database setup in `src/main/resources`.

**When I want to login, first I need to enter login and password from oauth_client_details**

If you use `oauth`, you have to know your application structure. Oauth2 have the following flow -

1. Authorization Code Grant
2. Implicit
3. Client Credential Grant
4. Password Grant

In my application, I use `Implicit` because of - We have

1. Server REST API (spring-boot)
2. Web Site (client)
3. Mobile App (client)
4. Customer/User (Actual User)

So according to `oauth`, client(web site or mobile app) need to authenticate itself.
Otherwise, you cannot get `access_token`. Read more [here](https://oauth.net/2/).

Comment: Thank you!
I use "Client Credential Grant". I created resource and Authorization in one place.
I created oauth_client_details too. 
When I want to receive a token, I need to enter login and password from oauth_client_details after that I enter username and password for a user.

Comment: I enter login and password from oauth_client_details, because I want to tell my Authorization server that's all ok?

Comment: Can I tune it without "oauth_client_details"?